# When does it makes sense to move a length getter out of the loop?

Tags: performance, optimization, language-agnostic

Consider the following (not in any particular language):

```
for (i=0; i<list.length(); i++) { ... }
```

Some people prefer to rewrite it as:

```
int len = list.length()
for (i=0; i<len; i++) { ... }
```

This would make sense if getting the length via `list.length()` was anything other than O(1). But I don't see any reason why this would be the case. Regardless of the data type, it should be trivial to add a length field somewhere and update it whenever the size changes.

Is there a common data type where getting or updating the length is not O(1)? Or is there another reason why someone would want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is a micro-optimization but **a valid one** (not implying it should be done, but that it can increase speed - unnoticeable speedup most likely). The reason this is valid is because of **aliasing**.

`length` can be modified inside the loop and a non-intrusive compiler *might* not be able to tell whether it is modified or not. Ergo, it will have to read the value every time, as opposed to accessing it once, before the loop.

The difference can be even more noticeable if the length is retrieved via a method call - like you'd do in C++:

```
int len = vect.size();
```

Comment: `vector::size()` is not O(1) ?

Comment: @Confluence it makes no difference. `int x = y * z;` is also `O(1)`, but it's not as fast as `int x = 0` (also `O(1)`). A program that runs every time in 1 hour is slower than a program that runs every time in 1 second, yet both are in `O(1)`.

Comment: Depending on what the loop does - in particular if you call a function with the variable-length item - the compiler probably won't know if it changes. If it DOES know length doesn't change it can also unroll the loop for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you are accessing a property directly, not using a getter (function call). That is probably always faster than a method call. Even if there was a method call, many languages are smart enough to optimize it.